Flatmap for deeply nested lists
I have the following list in Python:
N = [1, [2, 2], [[3, 3], 3], [[[4, 4], 4], 4], [[[[5, 5], 5], 5], 5]]

and I want to flatten it out and get a list of lists like this
[[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5,5]]

I tried:
sum(map(lambda x: [x, x, x], [x]), N)

but it doesn't work.

I can see no logical reason to think that would work. What's x? res? Is one of them N? What specifically does "doesn't work" mean? Give a [mre].

yes, it is N.. updated the question.

Result is still a NameError. Actually test what you're posting before posting it.

Honestly, this question seems like a duplicate since there are a lot of questions and answers for flattening a list in python.

@MilosStojanovic: Though confusingly, they seem to want to group and nest as well (e.g. the 1 at top-level becomes its own sublist).

What is the rule for the regrouping into sublists? That the values be the same? Or are you grouping by their position in the top-level list? That is, is an input like [1, [2,3]] possible, and if so, should it become [[1], [2, 3]], or [[1], [2], [3]]?

You can do:
from itertools import groupby, chain
flatten = lambda N: chain.from_iterable(map(flatten, N)) if isinstance(N, list) else [N]
[list(g) for _, g in groupby(flatten(N))]

Output:
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]


chaining with sum is a bad practice (inefficient), use itertools.chain as the doc recommends.

thanks for pointing out, OP was using sum so I used sum. changed it to itertools chain.

You can save yourself some unnecessary intermediate lists by getting rid of the list() in lambda, and just let it return an arbitrary iterable (typically a chain object, sometimes a list); groupby will work just fine on it either way. I'd also recommend making it an actual def function, not a lambda (so it knows its own name in case of tracebacks, is picklable and therefore usable for multiprocessing and the like, etc.). Named lambdas are for code golf, nothing else.

agree. I saved list out of it. And I would leave the decision to write it as def function to user which is straightforward.

You can flatten each item conditionally using recursion:

Note: This assumes that the nested lists are already sorted correctly, and that each first-level depth group will consist of identical values. This will avoid the need to explicitly group.

#!/usr/bin/env python3

def flat_group(nested_list):
    def flatten(el):
        if not isinstance(el, list):
            return [el]
        flat_list = []
        for sub in el:
            flat_list.extend(flatten(sub))
        return flat_list
        
    return [flatten(sub) for sub in nested_list]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = flat_group([1, [2, 2], [[3, 3], 3], [[[4, 4], 4], 4], [[[[5, 5], 5], 5], 5]])
    print(result)  # [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]

Here's more list-comprehension:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def flat_group(nested_list):
    def flatten(el):
        return [x for sub in el for x in flatten(sub)] if isinstance(el, list) else [el]

    return [flatten(sub) for sub in nested_list]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = flat_group([1, [2, 2], [[3, 3], 3], [[[4, 4], 4], 4], [[[[5, 5], 5], 5], 5]])
    print(result)  # [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]

And here is a lambda version:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

f1=lambda l: [f2(s) for s in l]
f2=lambda e: [x for s in e for x in f2(s)] if isinstance(e, list) else [e]

# [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
print(f1([1, [2, 2], [[3, 3], 3], [[[4, 4], 4], 4], [[[[5, 5], 5], 5], 5]]))


This works for me:
def f(x, ll):
    if (isinstance(x, list)):
        for e in x:
            f(e, ll)     
    else:
        ll.append(x)
        return

l = [1, [2, 2], [[3, 3], 3], [[[4, 4], 4], 4], [[[[5, 5], 5], 5], 5]]
lout = []

for entry in l:
    li = []
    f(entry, li)
    lout.append(li)

print(lout)

Output:
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]


Try:
def flatten(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for v in obj:
            yield from flatten(v)
    else:
        yield obj


N = [1, [2, 2], [[3, 3], 3], [[[4, 4], 4], 4], [[[[5, 5], 5], 5], 5]]

out = [list(flatten(v)) for v in N]
print(out)

Prints:
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]


Here is one option in the classical functional style, using recursion, pattern matching and structural construction/deconstruction:
N = [1, [2, 2], [[3, 3], 3], [[[4, 4], 4], 4], [[[[5, 5], 5], 5], 5]]

def flatten(n):
    match n:
        case []: return []
        case [*hd], *tl: return [*flatten(hd), *flatten(tl)]
        case hd, *tl: return [hd, *flatten(tl)]

def groupflat(n):
    match n:
        case []: return []
        case [*hd], *tl: return [flatten(hd), *groupflat(tl)]
        case hd, *tl: return [[hd], *groupflat(tl)]

groupflat(N)   # outputs: [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]

